# Stay Safe? Roger Roger

Tags: wordplay

hope all is well!

Back with a familiar puzzle, but for those that don't know the rules are as follows:

The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions. There are seven tiles. Place one tile in each region so that the four tiles in any one ellipse can be re-arranged to make an eight-letter solution to the corresponding clue!  Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: I think "Carefully like Rogers?" could be rot13(tvatreyl).

Comment: And then the top-left would be rot13(raqnatre).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three words are:

RISK:

> ENDANGER (to put something at risk)

CAREFULLY LIKE ROGERS:

> GINGER (Ginger Rogers was a famous dancer, and "gingerly" = "carefully")

E'S:

> ENERGIES (E is a common abbreviation for "energy")

So, reading across the rows:

> DA - EN - ES
>  NG - ER - GI
>  LY

I initially got sidetracked on "E's" by thoughts of

> the Shamen song "Ebenezer Goode", which involves repeatedly singing "E's are good" - we have EN, ER, and ES is pretty close to EZ.